# Installing all packages in Miktex using command line

Tags: packages, miktex, miktex2.9

Is there any command to install all packages using the command-line in miktex like

```
mpm --import-all
```

except from a online repository like `--install-all`.Although this doesn't work.

Is there any other command to install all packages using `mpm` from the command prompt

I need this because my computer will have internet access only once and I want to install all the packages at one go

Comment: You can use the `--upgrade` switch. Beside this you could use `mpm --list >package-list.txt`, edit the txt file and then use it it in `mpm --install-some=package-list.txt` (use the `--admin` switch if needed).

Comment: If you haven't an installation yet, simply use the setup wizard to get a complete installation directly: https://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/setupwiz.html

Comment: I have a installation already installed on my computer

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Your solution is not working

Comment: I made three suggestions. How should I know which one you used and what exactly you did?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  I did the mpm --list one. I created the list.txt then did mpm --install-some=package-list.txt with admin but it still did not work

Comment: Well I wrote between the two commands "edit the txt file". And my *first* suggestion was what you now added as answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to upgrade your Miktex installation to the highest level is by running

> `mpm --admin --verbose --package-level=complete --upgrade`

This installs all packages at once.

Comment: I joined this community just to upvote this answer. But, this does not work successfully if server does not respond/package name is not found.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I am not violating protocol here, but I would like to answer the question that "should have been asked," rather than as-asked.

MikTeX (and TeXLive) may be installed as "portable" versions. For MikTeX, it is here: https://miktex.org/portable and for TeXLive, it is configurable when you execute the downloaded installer (Windows or Linux), see instructions here: https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

When installed as portable, TeX does not need (and should not have) administrative privileges. You may install to a USB device, and carry it around for use on other computers. You may also include custom files in the `texmf-local` directory, so they are part of your setup wherever you go. The only potential issue (as far as I know) is if you are using `fontspec` to find Open Type fonts in the operating system, rather than within TeX. But in that case, if you have the font licenses, you can place the fonts in your portable `texmf-local` fonts directory.

Once you have it loaded and running, you may (if you wish) create a zip archive of the whole thing, and store it somewhere on your main computer. That way, if the portable installation ever fails, you can revert to the zipped backup.

On this user forum, there are many frantic posts about MikTeX being unable to update, download, or run. In nearly every case, that has to do with Windows file permissions. The portable installation avoids those problems.

Works for me!